# How to set two views background color same/equal in code

Tags: android, kotlin

I tried doing:

```
view1.background = view2.background
```

but it did not do anything. I then tried getting the background of view2 and did something like:

```
view1.setBackgroundColor(view2.getBackgroundColor)
```

However, there is no function to get background color of a view. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a method `setBackgroundColor`  to set the view the background.  we can also use the `setBackground` to set. we see they source code.

```
public void setBackgroundColor(@ColorInt int color) {
        if (mBackground instanceof ColorDrawable) {
            ((ColorDrawable) mBackground.mutate()).setColor(color);
            computeOpaqueFlags();
            mBackgroundResource = 0;
        } else {
            setBackground(new ColorDrawable(color));
        }
    }

public void setBackground(Drawable background) {
        //noinspection deprecation
        setBackgroundDrawable(background);
    }
```

the param for `setBackgroundColor` is an int color, but the API gives a method `getBackground`, it returns the drawable.

```
public Drawable getBackground() {
        return mBackground;
    }
```

so we can do as the following:

```
Drawable background = v1.getBackground();
v2.setBackground(background)
```

At the same, if we want to use the `setBackgroundColor` to do it, we have to get the int color. but that it **requires the background is** `ColorDrawable`

```
ColorDrawable background = (ColorDrawable)v1.getBackground();
int color = background.getColor();
v2.setBackgroundColor(color)
```

so I suggest you use the first way. that make the two view background same.

for the reason, why you can not directly assign the value. that because after the background set, **the UI thread in android needs to reDraw**, in that situation the config can take the effect. if you want to know more, you can see the `setBackgroundDrawable` method in view source code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do more methods and get it as this

```
 j.background = buttonContinueFirst?.background?.current
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        View view1 = findViewById(R.id.view1);
        View view2 = findViewById(R.id.view2);
        ColorDrawable viewColor = (ColorDrawable) view1.getBackground();
        int colorId = viewColor.getColor();

        view2.setBackgroundColor(colorId);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.